# How to convert a complicated (nested) json to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a very weird json file with a lot of nesting in it. I need to convert it into a Pandas dataframe.
The Json looks something like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "page1": {
      "last_name": "suraj",
      "first_name": "singh",
      "dob": "2020-06-02",
      "gender": "Male",
      "address1": "asdf",
      "city": "asdf",
      "state": "ID",
      "Zip": "34324",
      "phone": "2343243242",
      "emailaddress": "suraj.singh@fugetroncorp.com",
      "ethnicity": "adsf",
      "url": " 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",
      "meds": [
        [
          "asdf"
        ]
      ],
      "guardian": false,
      "guardianName": "N/A",
      "optout": false,
      "currentDate": "06-30-2020",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "asdf"
        }
      ]
    }
```

How can I create a proper structured dataFrame using this so that I can export it into a CSV for a better understanding.

Comment: Will this help  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-json-to-csv-in-python/

Comment: Yes but I need to use the dataframes first before appending to CSV.